# COUNT inside UNION ALL leads to skipping expected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have a simple articles and comments table. I want to display the articles along with their comments. I want to union with one select with the comments and another select without the comments on the same table. I have article number 1 with 1 comment and article number 2 with no comments and article number 3 with 2 comments.

The articles table:

```
articles.id | articles.content
   1        |  test article
   2        |  test another
   3        |   test third
```

The comments table:

```
comments.id | comments.aid | comments.comment
  1         |   1          |  bad one
  2         |   3          |  very good
  3         |   3          |   good
```

I use the following query to get the results.

```
SELECT articles.id AS article_id,
comments.id AS comment_id,
comment
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.aid = articles.id
UNION ALL
SELECT articles.id AS article_id,
NULL,
NULL
FROM articles
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY article_id DESC
```

The result I get which is correct:

```
article_id | comment_id | comment
   3       | 3          | good
   3       | 2          | very good
   3       | NULL       | NULL
   2       | NULL       | NULL
   2       | NULL       | NULL
   1       | NULL       | NULL
   1       | 1          | bad one
```

Now if I want to count the comments also I add COUNT to the query and it becomes:

```
SELECT articles.id AS article_id,
comments.id AS comment_id,
comment ,
COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) AS count_comments
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.aid = articles.id
UNION ALL
SELECT articles.id AS article_id,
NULL,
NULL ,
NULL
FROM articles
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY article_id DESC
```

Now the results change after adding the the count column and not all rows are outputted:

```
article_id | comment_id | comment   | count_comments
  3        | NULL       | NULL      |  NULL
  2        | NULL       | NULL      |  NULL  
  1        | NULL       | NULL      |  NULL
  1        | 1          | bad one   |  3
```

Now the comments aren't displayed except the comment of article 1, ID(2) should be displayed twice for the 2 select commands, and ID(3) should be displayed 3 times (1 for the second select command and 2 for the first select commands as there are 2 comments)

The correct results that I expect:

```
article_id | comment_id | comment   | count_comments
   3       | 3          | good      |   2 
   3       | 2          | very good |   2
   3       | NULL       | NULL      |   NULL  
   2       | NULL       | NULL      |   NULL
   2       | NULL       | NULL      |   NULL
   1       | NULL       | NULL      |   NULL 
   1       | 1          | bad one   |    1
```

I don't know why adding count leads to ths.

Thanks

Comment: much better if you can give sample data with desired output in tabular format.

Comment: do a separate query to get the count...

Comment: that wouldn't be one query as I i will have to do it for each row I output...it would be much better if done in one query @nathanhayfield

Comment: Where's the resulting `COUNT()` column?  Could you add that to your ending data, please?

Comment: I put sample tables for illustration @JW.

Comment: Sorry @Clockwork-Muse added it to the results as I forgot to do so

Comment: So if I can see with article id 2, you get null out with comments, and null without comments, in both cases. With article 3, you get the 2 comments, and then an extra null for no comments. What are you trying to acheive on the whole? I dont think you require a UNION ALL here.

Comment: the database scheme i use is much more complex than...i'm just using this for illustration of the problem. So yes i have to use the union @Octopi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `count()` it affects only the first subquery.  So, that subquery is only returning one row rather than multiple rows.

I'm having problems uploading SQL today, but I think you want something in this form:

```
select articles.id AS article_id, comments.id AS comment_id, comment,
       COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) AS count_comments
from ((subquery1) union all
      (subquery2)
     ) t
group by article_id
order by article_id desc
```

I assume that you are trying to get all articles included.  You don't need the `union all`.  Your first query is sufficient (because of the `left join`):

```
select articles.id AS article_id, comments.id AS comment_id, comment,
       COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) AS count_comments
from articles left join
     LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.aid = articles.id
group by article_id
ORDER BY article_id DESC
```

In the results that you say are correct, you have two rows for article 2, both with NULLs.  Is this really what you want?  If you want to add that, then put this before the `order by`:

```
union all
select distinct article_id, NULL, NULL, NULL
from articles
```

Comment: isn't there a way to do it without subqueries as there are performance hit on a large scale? thanks :)

Comment: The database scheme i use is actually much more complex than that...i'm just putting this for illustration. I need to use the union.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel . . . See the last part.  Just use the query with that union all glommed on (and the `order by` at the end).  It is unusual, though, to see a query that intentionally produces duplicates.

Comment: yup so the GROUP should have been added to the first SELECT not the  second one :) thanks Gordon :)